# How to make custom component style for different screen sizes with Ant Design

Tags: css, responsive-design, antd

I am trying to figure out how can I check what is my current screen size and based on that set a specific width/height with ant design. With the last version **5+** of **antd** I am using design token, not less css.

More specifically I am looking for a way to do exactly what the Grid component is doing, I want to just pass information for `xs, sm, md, lg, xl, xxl` that should scale my component.  I could not find how this should be done in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`useBreakpoint`](https://ant.design/components/grid#components-grid-demo-usebreakpoint) hook and a custom `js/ts` file to handle your styles.

```
/**
 * component.js/ts
 */
import Styles from "path/to/styles";

function Index() {
  const S = Styles();

  return <Input style={S.Input} />;
}

/**
 * styles.js/ts
 */
import { CSSProperties } from "react";
import { Grid } from "antd";

type StylesType = {
  Input: CSSProperties;
  OtherComponent: CSSProperties;
};

const { useBreakpoint } = Grid;

function Styles(): StylesType {
  const breakpoints = useBreakpoint();

  const Input: CSSProperties = {
    width: (() => {
      // you can now use any breakpoint and 
      // return different styles based
      if (breakpoints.xs) return "100%";
      if (breakpoints.sm) return "50%";
      if (breakpoints.md) return "25%";
      if (breakpoints.lg) return "10%";
      // default style
      return "100px";
    })()
  };

  const OtherComponent: CSSProperties = (() => {
    if (breakpoints.xs) return {
      width: '100%',
      color: 'red'
    }

    if(breakpoints.sm) return {
      width: '100px',
      color: 'blue'
    }
  })()

  return {
    Input,
    OtherComponent
  };
}

export default Styles;
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-9-0-forked-g84ww5?file=/demo.tsx) is a working codesandbox example.

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice, thank you. I was looking exactly for that, wasn't sure where to access the xs,sm etc.. But you also gave me a full example, awesome!